# How to bind a textblock's text through XAML using a property?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding

I am working on a Silverlight application, and I want to bind the simple text property of textblock through a property of string type.

What I did was:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Code behind:

```
public string Name{get;set;}

Name = "Testing..!";
```

but it will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on anatoliiG's answer (which will work): Data binding refers to properties on the `DataContext` property of the current element by default.  This means that your

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

is actually translated to

> Set the value of the `Text` property to `this.DataContext.Name`

(`DataContext` is inherited, so if it is not explicitly set on the `TextBlock` it will check the parent, then the parent of the parent etc etc)

You can resolve your problem in one of two ways:

1. You can set the value of `this.DataContext` on the parent to the parent itself (as anatoliiG suggests).  This means that when it looks up `this.DataContext.Name` it will be checking the `Page` itself, which is where your `Name` property is found.
2. You can change your `Binding` so it looks at the `Page` instead of `Page.DataContext` when it is looking up bindings.  You can achieve this using the `RelativeSource` markup extension:

This translates to:

> Find the first ancestor of the `TextBlock` that is of type `Page`, and bind to the `Name` property on that object

As a final note, you will also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `DataContext` object if you are going to ever change the value of `Name`.

Oh, and you *should* be using view models as the `DataContext` instead of the `Page` itself!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is: in `Page_Loaded` event set `LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;`. But it is more hack, than good practice.

You should take a look into MVVM pattern and `INotifyPropertyChanged` and create ViewModel which will contain this property.